# ¿Qué debo hacer para enviar email de verificación en mi app desde el back con nodeJs, nodemailer teniendo el dominio en godaddy?

Tags: nodejs, angular, hosting, nodemailer

Tengo contratado un dominio por ejemplo en godaddy.
¿Cómo puedo enviar emails de verificación o cualquier otra cosa que lleven mi nombre de dominio?
Quiero hacer la app con nodejs y nodemailer. He visto muchos ejemplos pero no se lo necesario respecto al tema de servidor de correo.
Los ejemplos los entiendo pero,

**¿Tengo que contratar algo más aparte del dominio o qué es lo que se debe hacer?**

¿Cómo trabajais vosotros con este tema de los correos? Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno antes que nada asumo que sabes Javascript, y que has realizado lo siguiente:

1. Tiene tu App server de NodeJs funcional
2. Estas usando NodeMailer dentro de esa app
3. tienes una ruta (ej: localhost:3000/send-mail) que recibe el mail como POST sobre dicha ruta

¿Tengo que contratar algo más aparte del dominio o qué es lo que se debe hacer?

Lo ideal es poseer un servicio externo capaza de entregar email masivo que te entregue una API con **SMTP**, yo uso estos 2:

- SendinBlue https://www.mailersend.com/  te deja enviar hasta 300mail/dia GRATIS **Facil de configurar solo con tu correo
- MailerSend https://www.mailersend.com/ te deja enviar hasta 12.000 mails/mes (400/dia) GRATIS **Este es mas dificil de configurar ya que validan muchas cosas y te piden Credt Card

Ambos te entregan un servicio API de SMTP muy eficiente, de esto solo requieres:

- host: servidor smtp
- port: pueto del sevidor smtp: number
- autuser: usuario smtp: string
- autpass: clave de smtp: string

Puedes seguir mi ejemplo de Servidor de correos con NodeMailer aqui:
https://github.com/Jucema89/serverMail

Esto sirve para enviar Mensajes de mail de Notificaciones.

Para enviar mails para recuperacion de contrasenas y o confirmacion de creacion de cuentas ya es otro asunto.

Honestamente para eso lo que he usado y visto usar es integracion con firebase y el sistema de confirmacion de cuentas y recuperacion de contrasenas que brindan ellos: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth?hl=es-419

Espero haberte ayudado en algo.

Happy Coding.